# Django 'symmetrical' explained

Tags: django, django-models

I don't understanding how Django 'symmetrical' works, I read the documentation part about it but it's too short and searched about it but and I don't really understand it...can anyone explain difference between a symmetrical and non symmetrical relationship in a little more detail?

Comment: https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/08/14/creating-recursive-symmetrical-many-to-many-relationships-in-django/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Symmetrical relationship**

```
class User(models.Model)
...
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self")
...
alice = User()
bob = User()
bob.friends.add(alice)
```

Now, Bob is an Alice's friend and Alice is a Bob's friend

**Non symmetrical relationship**

```
class User(models.Model)

     ...
     parents = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False)
 ...
 alice = User()
 bob = User()
 bob.parent.add(alice)
```

Now, Alice is a Bob's parent, but Bob isn't an Alice parent