# In Django, what does symmetrical=True do?

Tags: django, django-models

For example:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='ContactRelationship', symmetrical=False)
```

What does the `symmetrical=False` parameter do?

When should it be left as `True`, and when should it be set as `False`?

How does this settings affect the database (does it create extra columns etc)?

Comment: `symmetrical=True` results in creating two rows for a single relationship between two objects because it is bidirectional. For example: If `A` is a friend of `B`, then `B` is a friend of `A` so we need two separate rows in the friends table where first one will indicate the relation `A -> B` and second one is `B -> A`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is what is says in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical):

> Only used in the definition of ManyToManyFields on self. Consider the following model:

```
from django.db import models
```

> 

```
class Person(models.Model):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

> When Django processes this model, it identifies that it has a `ManyToManyField` on itself, and as a result, it doesn’t add a `person_set` attribute to the `Person` class. Instead, the `ManyToManyField` is assumed to be `symmetrical` – that is, if I am your friend, then you are my friend.

By default, the value of `symmetrical` is True for Many to Many Field which is a bi-directional relationship.

**Using a through table (symmetrical=False):**

But you can also imagine a situation where you don't need this type of relationship so you can add `symmetrical=False`. And, this can be achieved by using a through table because by default `symmetrical` is `False` if you use a through table:

> Recursive relationships using an intermediary model are always defined as non-symmetrical – that is, with `symmetrical=False` – therefore, there is the concept of a `“source”` and a `“target”`. In that case `'field1'` will be treated as the `“source”` of the relationship and `'field2'` as the `“target”`.

So you can imagine a situation where you do need the direction i.e. let's say there is a `Node` model and it has a relationship with itself using a through table. If we didn't have the requirement of direction here we could go with the example shown earlier. But now we also need a direction from one node to another where one being `source` and another one being `target` and due to nature of this relationship it cannot be symmetrical.

Comment: Thanks. To confirm if I understood correctly: if the ManyToManyField is symmetrical, does that simply take everything that would have been in Person.person_set and lump it into Person.friends? And if I understand correctly, it's a Django thing, not a database thing - we can switch back and forth between symmetrical True or False without making any changes to database migrations?

Comment: It's totally a django thing but the migration would happen though it won't affect the DB. It behaves more like `blank` keyword which if you add to a field would result in a migration though it is not directly related to the DB but is only used in django forms.

Comment: father nodes and child nodes are always defined as non-symmetrical

Comment: Working link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

Comment: @thrillhouse Thanks. I have updated the link in the answer.

Answer (score 38):

Let's say you have two instances of Contact, John and Judy. You may decide to make John a contact of Judy. Should this action also make Judy a contact of John? If so, `symmetrical=True`. If not, `symmetrical=False`

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand it now. But, what's the purpose of having two row with the first and second columns flipped? If `Judy.contacts` contains a through object pointing to John, couldn't one simply do something like `John.contacts_set` to get that same through object originating from Judy? Or, just go through the table again and treat column 1 like column 2, and column 2 like column 1 for the effect of symmetry?

Comment: I believe that, if you are using an intermediary model i.e. `through=`, you must set `symmetrical=False`. In any case, I'm not certain but I doubt that the rows are duplicated when `symmetrical=True`. Bear in mind that there is an ORM separating your code from the DB; so, that flag more likely affects the structure of the DB queries than the structure of the DB itself. But I'm not an expert so maybe someone else will weigh in on this!

Answer (score 4):

**Symmetrical relationship**

```
class User(models.Model)
...
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self")
...
alice = User()
bob = User()
bob.friends.add(alice)
```

Now, Bob is an Alice's friend and Alice is a Bob's friend

**Non symmetrical relationship**

```
class User(models.Model)

     ...
     parents = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False)
 ...
 alice = User()
 bob = User()
 bob.parent.add(alice)
```

Now, Alice is a Bob's parent, but Bob isn't an Alice parent.

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34998422/5993109